# Why HttpClient of JDK11 can not read full body string?

Tags: java, http, hex, java-11

In my application, I use JDK11 HttpClient to send http request to server.
Server encrypt response into hex string.
Client code may like below:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(new URI("xxx"))
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(encryptBody));
    .headers(xxx)
    .build();
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpRequest.BodyHandlers.ofString());
// here returned body is just first part.
System.out.println("body : " + response.body());
```

Example:
server returns:
`dfb3132c37f32cb93c78760749a6d9b0024e1 b0c5aa1dcd0bb1f02d611b72f0f5a073059475e659dd7aca7aad48e50f151e0ac215ab35eb8e041e569d779bd1a359007e0269dce3f3968ae070514d5ffd1591dc8b1b3e643c72888c9f95f9021071c3d8b7c8e540cc54df4762cb6a2086facac86e17cf023879936f725dfda5c60d97097785e2a62885cf6342a0d616ad632d7769518cc68720dd1d4bc9e20560e831a3eb6140747ae1f35e7fa136303b0df2fd7820fb2d1d1e467`
But here response body is:
`dfb3132c37f32cb93c78760749a6d9b0024e1b0c5aa1dcd0bb1f02d611b72f0f5a073059475e659dd7aca7aad48e50f151e0ac215ab35eb8e041e569d779bd1a359007e0269dce3f3968ae070514d5f`

And I have tried to use OkHttpClient to make request. It works well.
So, it's a client issue. But I cannout figure it out.
Any response will be highly appreciated.

---

OkHttpClient code works well, code may like below:

```java
final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, encryptBody);
Request req = new Request.Builder()
    .post(body)
    .url(xxx)
    .headers(xxx)
    .build();
Call call = client.newCall(req);
Response rep = call.execute();
System.out.println("body : " + rep.body.string());
```

---

Server use netty. Core handler like below:

```java
class HttpResponseEncipher extends MessageToMessageEncoder<Netty4HttpResponse> {
    private static final String PROPERTY_DO_NOT_SPLIT = "es.unsafe.do_not_split_http_responses";

    private final boolean isSpiltResponse;

    private final int splitThreshold;

    HttpResponseEncipher() {
        isSpiltResponse = Booleans.parseBoolean(System.getProperty(PROPERTY_DO_NOT_SPLIT), false);
        splitThreshold = (int) (NettyAllocator.suggestedMaxAllocationSize() * 0.99);
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Netty4HttpResponse msg, List<Object> out) {
        ByteBuf buf = msg.content();
        FullHttpResponse rep = msg.replace(encryptContent(buf));
        if (isSpiltResponse || rep.content().readableBytes() <= splitThreshold) {
            out.add(rep);
        } else {
            out.add(createPart(rep));
            ByteBuf content = rep.content();
            while (content.readableBytes() > splitThreshold) {
                out.add(new DefaultHttpContent(content.readRetainedSlice(splitThreshold)));
            }
            out.add(new DefaultLastHttpContent(content.readRetainedSlice(content.readableBytes())));
        }
    }

    private HttpResponse createPart(FullHttpResponse rep) {
        return new DefaultHttpResponse(rep.protocolVersion(), rep.status(), rep.headers());
    }
    
    private ByteBuf encryptContent(ByteBuf source) {
        int len = source.readableBytes();
        byte[] body = new byte[len];
        source.readBytes(body, 0, len);
        byte[] encryptedBody = AuthorityManager.getXXX().encrypt(body);
        String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(encryptedBody);
        return Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(hexString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

And above this, there are `HttpContentCompressor`, `HttpResponseEncoder` and `ReadTimeoutHandler`.

Comment: How do you determine what is in the returned body?  Show us the code that does that.  Also, what is the actual class of the `response` object?

Comment: @StephenC I use OkHttpClient to request server and then return the full body. I have updated the okhttp request and server code. Thanks.

Comment: Please answer the 2 questions that I actually asked ... above.

Comment: 1 System.out.println("body : " + response.body()) 2 string

Comment: OK ... I can't see what the problem is.  I suggest that you attaching a debugger to the client and looking at what is actually received within the HttpClient code ... and where the characters go missing.

Comment: There are a few possible explanations.  These *include*: 1) the server is not sending what you think, 2) the received response body string is not what you think, 3) there is a subtle difference between the actual code and the code you showed us, 4) something between the server and client is rewriting the data, 5) there is a bug in Java 11 HttpClient.  Investigate each of these possibilities.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to debug it later.

Comment: @shanfeng I would say the root cause is you are modifying response (encrypting it and converting to hex) but fails to actualize content-length header, not sure it was set before conversion though.

Comment: @shanfeng, Have you compared the body content of the Request sent by HttpClient and OkHttpClient on the server side?

Comment: @StephenC I got it. HttpResponseEncipher rewrite contents without handling content-length. OkHttp works well as it use compress in the header. The content-length will be recalculated in the compression.

Answer (score 0):

Recalculating content-length after rewrite content.

```java
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Netty4HttpResponse msg, List<Object> out) {
    ByteBuf buf = msg.content();
    ByteBuf encryptBuf = encryptContent(buf);
    FullHttpResponse rep = msg.replace(encryptBuf);
    rep.headers().set("content-length", encryptBuf.readableBytes()); // recalc content length
    rep.headers().set("Content-Type", "text/plain");  // rewrite content type
    ...
}
```